# Preventing a global component getting triggered twice in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I use the same global component in a parent view and child (to the parent) in VueJs?

At the moment the global component is getting triggered twice when I trigger a function in the child component.

**Parent**

```
<ChildCompt ref="childCompt" />
<Modal ref="modalA" />

<div @click="triggerModalParent()">
  Trigger Modal
</div>
```

Trigger function `triggerModalParent`: `this.$refs.modalA.show();`

**Child**

```
<Modal ref="modalB" />
<div @click="triggerModalChild()">
  Trigger Modal
</div>
```

Trigger function `triggerModalChild`: `this.$refs.modalB.show();`

Comment: Can you add some code with your imports and trigger function?

Comment: @kuntervert - Added some examples. Du you need anything else? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using different refs for parent and child modal imports, at the moment your imports have the same ref, hence they both get triggered

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however i'm still getting 2 modals triggered!

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show me your change?

Comment: Yes - Just added it the example Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, can you describe what does "triggering twice" exactly mean in this context?

Comment: So basically 2 modals appear (on top of each other) - the first one is trigged from the parent and the second is the child (underneath). I know this as there are some props that aren't passed to the first modal (parent), however are show in the second modal.